# an stack app as a notebook

Tags: feature-request

Is there any stack app for this web site which like a note book. This site is my google and I wish to find an ability which let me to put my notes on that. I am looking for any feature or stack app which integrate to my askubuntu profile and let me to put my notes like some commands on that.So is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure if there's any Stack App that does this, I'm not sure why this task would need to be tied specifically to the Stack Exchange platform. Presumably, any *web annotation* software would do the job.

- ["Web annotation" on English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_annotation) (includes a detailed table of programs for this)

Credit is due to [words that end in GRY](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/147263/words-that-end-in-gry) who [suggested this in a comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13940/private-notes-about-a-question?cb=1#comment55305_13940) on [a similar question on Math.SE Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13940/private-notes-about-a-question?cb=1). You may want to check back at that question periodically, in case people post about particular web annotation programs that worked well (or in case someone posts about other solutions).

There's a Stack Exchange Q&A site specifically about StackApps. The site is called [stackpps](https://stackapps.com/). You might want to post a question there about this (after reading the [tour](https://stackapps.com/tour) and [help](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic), and [searching](https://stackapps.com/search) to see if it's already asked and answered). I did a cursory search there and didn't find anything, but you might have better luck, as I only put about thirty seconds of time and very little effort into it. :)